# pandas: trouble transforming dataframe into aggregated dataframe

Tags: pandas

I'm a new user of pandas. I have been going through the help docs, and trying various experiments (groupby(), multiindex, value_cuounts()). But I am not able to get the desired end result.

My dataframe is as follows (it is time indexed):

```
DATE, GROUP, X, Y, STATUS
2014-01-01  A  0 0 PASS
2014-01-01  A  0 1 FAIL
2014-01-01  A  1 0 PASS
2014-01-02  B  0 0 PASS
2014-01-02  B  0 1 PASS
2014-01-02  B  1 1 FAIL
....
```

The 'STATUS' column is of dtype=category. I would like to end up with a new dataframe that looks like as follows:

```
DATE GROUP STATUS  PCT
2014-01-01 A PASS 0.667
2014-01-01 A FAIL 0.333
2014-01-02 B PASS 0.667
2014-01-02 B FAIL 0.333
```

Essentially, for each group, I want to calculate the % of all status.

I have tried df.groupby('GROUP').value_counts()  followed by divide by sum() to calculate the percentages. That works OK. However, I lose the index information and I don't know to add it to the new dataframe to achieve the desired output above. There must be some easy way in pandas to do it, but I'm not seeing it.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the "index information"? Is it in the above example?

Comment: Is it group by just 'group' ? in that case does each group have exactly one date ? If not then it should be group by 'date' and 'group'

Comment: The index is the 'DATE'. As I mentioned, the data is indexed by date. Also each group has exactly one date. The data for a group is coming in once every day (discriminator is X,Y) and the group name is not repeated at a later date (i.e., it is unique).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on the 'DATE' and 'GROUP' columns, then call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on 'STATUS' column and call [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) / [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html#pandas.Series.count), `transform` will return a series aligned to your orig df, so it allows you to add it back as a new column:

```
In [64]:

df['PCT'] = df.groupby(['DATE','GROUP'])['STATUS'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts() / x.count())
df
Out[64]:
         DATE GROUP  X  Y STATUS        PCT
0  2014-01-01     A  0  0   PASS  0.6666667
1  2014-01-01     A  0  1   FAIL  0.3333333
2  2014-01-01     A  1  0   PASS  0.6666667
3  2014-01-02     B  0  0   PASS  0.6666667
4  2014-01-02     B  0  1   PASS  0.3333333
5  2014-01-02     B  1  1   FAIL  0.6666667
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I can do drop['X','Y'] followed by drop_duplicates() to get it to the desired format.