# pandas: trouble transforming dataframe into aggregated dataframe (part2)

Tags: pandas

This question is a continuation of a previous one: [pandas: trouble transforming dataframe into aggregated dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676476/pandas-trouble-transforming-dataframe-into-aggregated-dataframe)

Let's make the problem a bit more complicated. What if I have a table as shown below. STATUS is a categorical variable w/ 3 possible values. However, I would like the % occurrence of each STATUS (even if it is not present in the original data) by group.

```
            GROUP, X, Y, STATUS
2014-01-01  A  0 0 PASS
2014-01-01  A  0 1 FAIL
2014-01-01  A  1 0 PASS
2014-01-01  A  1 1 UNKNOWN
2014-01-02  B  0 0 PASS
2014-01-02  B  0 1 PASS
2014-01-02  B  1 1 FAIL
```

This should become as shown below. Note that for group 'B', I would like UNKNOWN 0.0 row to be generated as well even though it is not present in the original dataframe. Doing values_count() on a categorical will report 'UNKNOWN' frequency, but how to get it into the dataframe then w/ the indexing, etc? Thanks once again.

```
  GROUP STATUS  PCT
2014-01-01 A PASS 0.5
2014-01-01 A FAIL 0.25
2014-01-01 A UNKNOWN 0.25
2014-01-02 B PASS 0.667
2014-01-02 B FAIL 0.333
2014-01-02 B UNKNOWN 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I came up which seems a bit cumbersome. Maybe there is a much simpler way?

```
    import pandas as pd
    >>> a = pd.DataFrame({'G' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'X' : [0,1,2,0,1,2], 'Y' : [0,0,0,0,0,0], 'STATUS' : ['PASS', 'FAIL', 'PASS', 'UNKNOWN', 'PASS', 'PASS']})
    >>> t = pd.to_datetime('2015-06-03')
    >>> a.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series([t] * len(a.index))))
    >>> a['STATUS'] = a['STATUS'].astype('category', categories=['PASS', 'FAIL', 'UNKNOWN'])
                G   STATUS  X  Y
    2015-06-03  A     PASS  0  0
    2015-06-03  A     FAIL  1  0
    2015-06-03  A     PASS  2  0
    2015-06-03  B  UNKNOWN  0  0
    2015-06-03  B     PASS  1  0
    2015-06-03  B     PASS  2  0

    >>> b = a.groupby('G')['STATUS'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts() / x.count()).reset_index()
    >>> b.rename(columns={'level_1' : 'STATE', 0 : 'PCT'}, inplace=True)
    >>> b
   G    STATE       PCT
0  A     PASS  0.666667
1  A     FAIL  0.333333
2  A  UNKNOWN  0.000000
3  B     PASS  0.666667
4  B  UNKNOWN  0.333333
5  B     FAIL  0.000000

    >>> c = pd.merge(a,b, right_index=True, on=['G'])
    >>> c.drop(['STATUS', 'X', 'Y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    >>> c.drop_duplicates()
            G    STATE       PCT
2015-06-03  A     PASS  0.666667
2015-06-03  A     FAIL  0.333333
2015-06-03  A  UNKNOWN  0.000000
2015-06-03  B     PASS  0.666667
2015-06-03  B  UNKNOWN  0.333333
2015-06-03  B     FAIL  0.000000
```